# Query string parameter changes several times in a day - requests.get in python solution needed

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to automate the retrieval of data from this site, https://reports.bcogc.ca/ogc/f?p=200:21:3220363279557::NO::: 
The code below executes the csv download. The first time I run this code, the pandas df connects to the response and generates the data set.

The problem is that if I run the script after a while, instead of downloading the entire data history (30,000 rows+), it downloads just the most recent data (35 rows). I noticed that the query string parameter (params = params line) changes periodically, several times a day, and this causes the partial data download.

I don't want to keep changing the parameter so that I can get the full dataset each time I run the code. Is there a solution to this which is permanent and will not require me to manually input the new parameter each time ?

```
import requests
import io

cookies = {
    'ORA_WWV_APP_200': 'ORA_WWV-fmsm2gSKWuJAeAMWlkJVb24U',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.590107047.1541651761',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1288213293.1547007889',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://reports.bcogc.ca/ogc/f?p=200:21:3220363279557::NO:::',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('p', '200:21:3220363279557:CSV::::'),
)

response = requests.get('https://reports.bcogc.ca/ogc/f', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text), na_values = '-', low_memory=False)
```

Comment: Do you have a detailed description of how the parameter changes? It's a bit difficult to tell you how to implement something if you don't say what it is that you actually want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The site redirects to the url containing the new parameter. just get this new parameter from the url and request again with the updated parameter.